# How to get space between typography element and table in Material UI

Tags: material-ui

I have my page title setup with a table below it. But I need a space between the title and the table. What is the best practice for doing this with material ui?

````
<div style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'baseline' }}>
      <Grid
        container
        justify="center"
      >
        <Paper
          elevation={0}
        >
          <Box mt={5} mb={5} width={1200}>
            <Grid container justify="center" spacing={2}>
              <Grid item xs={7}>
                <Typography variant="h3" style={{ fontWeight: 600 }}>
                  Games List
                </Typography>
                <MaterialTable
                  columns={columns}
                  title="my games"
                  icons={tableIcons}
                  style={{ padding: '25px' }}
                />
               </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Box>
        </Paper>
        <Footer />
      </Grid>
    </div>
    ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a margin space like so:

```
<Typography variant="h3" style={{ fontWeight: 600, marginBottom: '16px' }}>
  Games List
</Typography>;
```

Change `16px` as your need

Demo Example:

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]